# JS insert string ${ }

Tags: javascript, string

I build a class in main.js using "use strict" as below:

```
class Compte{

    constructor(devise){
        this.solde = 0;
        this.devise = devise;
    }
.......

   toString(){

        console.log("The rest is  : ${this.devise} ${this.solde}.");
        //console.log("The rest is: ", this.devise, this.solde);
    }
}

let b1 = new Compte("CAD");
```

When I test in the console platform, as b1.toString(), the method of inserting directly the variable ${ } doesn't function. The second way is tested correctly.

Answer (score 5):

for template literals, you need to use backticks:

```js
const name = "Ethan";
console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
```